# android studio debugger not stepping in to another activity from mainactivity

Tags: android-studio, debugging

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling); //------ Here the debug control not stepping into the activity_scrolling code / breakpoints.
```

Tried different options in preference/debugger/stepping - any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.

setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);

----- This only sets a layout to the current activity even though it is meant for ScrollingActivity. This line loads the activity to Mainactivity. (Android doesn't seem to have 1 to 1 exclusive binding between layouts and activities. Do they?!)

You need to start the activity in order to use it and debug it.

So, add this below,

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScrollingActivity.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("key", "value"); //Optional parameters
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

This enables the second activity loaded and debugger navigates to breakpoints inside the second activity.